# Does Xamarin support Kotlin coroutines in a Xamarin Android Binding Library?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, kotlin-coroutines

I have an Android Binding Library with Kotlin code, and it exits whenever it hits runBlocking{} in the Kotlin code.

> E(28583:28691) ERROR [19] - The worker thread caught an exception:
>   Failed resolution of: Lkotlinx/coroutines/BuildersKt; E(28583:28691)
>   Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lkotlinx/coroutines/BuildersKt; ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Didn't find class "kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/de.mycompany.app.myproduct-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.mycompany.app.myproduct-1/lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

In my Kotlin AAR module, I have the following dependencies

> implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
>   => equivalent Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib
>   implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.1'
>               =>
>   equivalent Xamarin.????
>   implementation
>   "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1"
>       =>
>   equivalent Xamarin.????

I'm guessing that Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib doesn't include support for the Kotlinx coroutines.
Is there any way to get support for Kotlinx-coroutines in a Xamarin Android Binding library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, *Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib* doesn't include support for the Kotlinx coroutines.

In order to have the *Kotlinx-coroutines* in a Xamarin Android Binding library, you have to add the *KotlinX.Coroutines* NuGet package as a dependency of the app project and the binding library project.

So if you have something like this:

> MyAndroidApp.proj -> MyBindingLibrary.proj

Both project have to add the *KotlinX.Coroutines* dependency.

N.B. In my case, Microsoft's [binding](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.KotlinX.Coroutines.CoroutinesAndroid/1.3.4) was NOT working. I had to use Karamunting's [binding](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Karamunting.KotlinX.Coroutines.Android/1.4.2).